# How to do all the possible comparisons of 2 nodes in a linked list that is growing

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a program which I have some initial nodes in a linked list, and I need to put a pair of nodes inside a function `resolve(node *node 1, node* node2)`, this function can generate a new node or not, and I'm not alowed to compare the same pair of nodes more than one time, the condition for the function to stop is when there are no distinct nodes to be compared anymore.

° The elements of the singly linked list are being inserted at the end.

I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 days, but I can't think of a way to compare all the possible nodes, that fact that more nodes can be generated make the problem difficult to solve.

**@edit**

[image]

The black point is the first node where the distributive starts.

```
resolve(node* node1, node* nodesafter)
```

The elipse is the node generated.

But the only node generated is not being compared with the node at the top.

In this case 6 comparisons a being made, in my code only 5 are being made.

Comment: I presume a *singly-linked* list? (e.g. no `prev` pointer?). You can use two-levels of iteration beginning with `head` and `next`. Iterate from `next` to `tail` on the inner-iteration, then increment `head->next` and do it again. Very inefficient, but workable.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's a singly linked list with no head. Could you please show some pseudocode ? I didn't understand much of what you said.

Comment: Sure, it is like nested loop, you will iterate `type *outer = head; while (outer->next != NULL) { type *inner = head->next; while (inner != NULL) { /* do your comparison */; inner = inner->next; } outer = outer->next }`  (where `type` is whatever struct you are using for your `node`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks.

Comment: So, the new node must be inserted at the end, too? **and** be compared exactly once to any other node ? How many new nodes can be generated by one complete `N*(N-1)/2` pass?

Comment: @wildplasser The function resolve(node* n1, node* n2) will analyse if from the 2 given nodes it is possible to generate a new one.

Comment: @wildplasser In my program it is being inserted at the end, but it doesn't need exctly to be inserted at the end, but I only want to make sure all the nodes, including the new genarated one will be compared with previous as well till there's no more nodes to be compared.

Answer (score 2):

Well... you can loop through the list from first to last and compare all next nodes with current one.
In this case you ensure that all previous nodes was compared.
For example (JavaScript):

```
var list = new LinkedList();
fillList(list);
var current = list.first;
while(current.next !== null){
    var current2 = current.next;
    do{
        resolve(current, current2);
        current2 = current2.next;
    }while(current2 !== null);
    current = current.next;
}
```

Comment: Yes, like this. I would have coded it a bit differently, but there is nothing wrong with however you want to put the pieces together as long as they work correctly and are readable. Even a `for` makes sense here as well. (as does `while` or `do - white`).

Comment: @Roman Muravchuck I found a problema in this code, I think I didn't express my ideas well, could you please check my edit ?

Comment: The problem that newly created nodes is not compared with previous? In this case you need to compare newly created nodes with current and previous. Do this in the resolve() function.

Comment: @RomanMuravchuck the function resolve is to determine if from 2 nodes a new one can be generated, what could I do inside of it to make sure a new node will be compared with a previous exactly one time ?

Comment: Example (again JS):
`function resolve(curNode, nextNode){
    if( checkConditionForNewNode() ){
        var newNode = list.push(generateSomeData());
        resolve(curNode, newNode);
        var current = list.first;
        while(current !== null && current !== curNode){
            resolve(current, newNode);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
`
In case you always check just next nodes dont care about double comparison with previous.

Comment: @RomanMuravchuck I tested and it is still inconsistent, I will try to keep track of the nodes that I already computed  to avoid doing the same calculation, but anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: Be sure that you compare new node with previous up to the current. Nodes after current node will be compared on the next step, so don't check they with new node.